# how draw multiple canvas in single page?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to draw multiple canvas in single for this code?

I able to draw single canvas using my code.

i have different y data for every canvas and per page 6 canvas .how to draw in single page.

can you please give optimise code sample example?

here is example image:
[image]

Here is my single canvas draw Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160" style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

           var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#dbbd7a";
            ctx.fill();

            var fps = 60;
            var n = 1;


            var data = [
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
                148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, ];


            drawWave();

            function drawWave() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
                    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

                    // Drawing code goes here
                    n += 1;
                    if (n >= data.length) {
                        n = 1;
                    }
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(n, data[n]);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    ctx.clearRect(n+1, 0, 10, canvas.height);

                }, 1000 / fps);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, at first get your script into drawing multiple images before we talk about optimisations. Use a function that is given a `<canvas>` element and a `data` array for that, then call it multiple times. To optimize, use one function that is given an array of canvases and an array of data.

Comment: Do not use `setTimeout` *and* `requestAnimationFrame`, but only one of them. For a stable animation, you should also consider the actual current time (`Date.now()`).

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ezCL9/

Answer (score 2):

Did this kind of thing ages ago. I've just hacked together a quick example for you.

As Bergi says - you need to make a function that will draw arbitrary data on an arbitrary canvas. This example is a synthesizer like the ones used in MOD players and demo music-players, using webkitAudioContext - you can click on a sample to hear it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/rsNZB/

The synth core comes from a c++(c? - I forget) graphics/sound demo with the dubious name VoxelBukkake

After initializing the audio context, adding a canvas and it's associated audio data is as simple as:

```
addPlayableGraph(hihat);
```

EDIT:

A sample image:
[image]

Comment: can you please give sample for my example?

Comment: awesome. where did you get your instruments from..? got a link?

Comment: nevermind, got it ;) nice port of his c++ code. http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=20171

Comment: @purBin - tell me, how does this not fit your needs? What would you like that's different? I've drawn all of the individual samples for each sound. You could just draw (say) 100 or 1000 of them, using a counter or index to control which one you drew first. That would show an animated output when combined with RequestAnimationFrame or SetTimeout.